# Project Euler # 37 wrong result

Tags: c#

I'm currently solving the Project Euler problem #37 :

> The number 3797 has an interesting property. Being prime itself, it is possible to continuously remove digits from left to right, and remain prime at each stage: 3797, 797, 97, and 7. Similarly we can work from right to left: 3797, 379, 37, and 3.
>
> Find the sum of the only eleven primes that are both truncatable from left to right and right to left.
>
> NOTE: 2, 3, 5, and 7 are not considered to be truncatable primes.

So I did 2 methods 1 that removes digits from left to right and 1 that removes from right to left it gives the same results just as in the example. However I get 11 early primes that really happen to fit the truncatable number description like :

> 13, 17, 23, 31, 37, 53, 71, 73, 113, 131, 137

with sum of 699. The correct answer is 748317. I don't see any reason why the code is not giving the correct result or why the correct answer is not 699 instead. Why those numbers don't count as truncatable ?

```
private static void Main()
    {
        int countPrimes = 0;
        long sum = 0;
        long i = 13;
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        while (countPrimes < 11)
        {
            if (IsTruncatable(i))
            {
                countPrimes++;
                sum += i;
            }
            i+=2;
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        Console.WriteLine("Time to calculate in milliseconds : {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static bool IsPrime(long input) // sitoto na eratosten
    {
        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.Sqrt(input); i++)
        {
            if (input%i == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static bool IsTruncatable(long inputPrime)
    {
        char[] charDigits = inputPrime.ToString().ToCharArray();
        long[] digits = new long[charDigits.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < charDigits.Length; i++)
        {
            digits[i] = (int)char.GetNumericValue(charDigits[i]);
        }
        return RemoveDigitsLeft(digits) && RemoveDigitsRight(digits);
    }

    private static bool RemoveDigitsRight(IReadOnlyList<long> digits)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.Count; i++)
        {
            string tempNumber = string.Empty;
            for (int j = i; j < digits.Count; j++)
            {
                tempNumber += digits[j];
            }
            if (!IsPrime(long.Parse(tempNumber)))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static bool RemoveDigitsLeft(IReadOnlyList<long> digits)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.Count; i++)
        {
            string tempNumber = string.Empty;
            for (int j = 0; j < digits.Count - i; j++)
            {
                tempNumber += digits[j];
            }
            if (!IsPrime(long.Parse(tempNumber)))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: 1 is not a prime number, so any prime starting or ending in a 1 is not truncatable.

Comment: In order to solve this in a reasonable amount of time you should use the Sieve of Eratosthenes (or similar) to generate all the primes up to 748317 and just look for the 11 that match the requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response's to both of you i solved it now just needed the check that @Dennis_E suggested and it runs in 1050-1100 ms

Comment: I didn't use the sieve because we don't know how much is the result i just looked for it and i think it's kinda unfair to just put the result there.. We cant tell at which prime we need to stop.Also the sieve is not much faster - 100-150 ms